# A 404 error if slug begins with “id-” on multilingual website with Indonesian language in Django 3.0

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-i18n, django-errors

http://example.com/de/id-button/ - 200 OK

http://example.com/id/id-button/ - 200 OK

http://example.com/any-other-slug/ - 200 OK

http://example.com/id-button/ - 404 error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in example.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
id/
The current path, id-button/, didn't match any of these.
```

urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', cache_page(cache_homepage)(homepage_views.index), name='index'),
    path('search/', search_views.search, name='search'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', item_views.item, name='item'),
    prefix_default_language=False,
)
```

The item have a slug field in DB "id-button".
If I rename this to "idbutton":
http://example.com/idbutton/ - 200 OK

But I need to have url like: http://example.com/id-button/

**Update:**
It's accepted as a bug, but it's not moving for now:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31540

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an interaction between `LocaleMiddleware` and `i18n_patterns`.

When `LocaleMiddleware` sees the request coming in, it tries to parse the language from the request. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/92507bf3ea4dc467f68edf81a686548fac7ff0e9/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L46 for the regular expression used. The allowed format is: any sequence of word characters, and optionally a dash and more word characters, after that it expects either the end of the string, or a `/`. In this case, it matches `id-domain/`, and understands that `id-domain` is the language prefix for that request, causing Django to activate the `id` language.

Then, the request goes through the URL routing layer, reaching as one of the first stops the https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/resolvers.py#L301 . The `get_language()` command returns `id`, and the prefix thus searched for is `id/`, which `id-domain/` does not match against. As the `LocalePrefixPattern` is the top-level resolver, it not matching causes nothing else to be tried.

(Is it a bug in Django? Maybe, I'd expect it seeing `id-domain/` as language would make it also be used for language-prefix for the URL resolving. But even then it might not resolve your problem)

Comment: Thanks @Sjoerd Job Postmus, 
I thought that it's somehow connected with locales, like en-US, id-ID.

It would be cool if it's possible to limit "optionally a dash and more word characters" to predefined list of values of locales, that can be also overwritten in settings.py

Good candidate for a list of languages and territories for this is https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/37/supplemental/language_territory_information.html
But I think it's a long story.

Could you please suggest a "temporary" workaround for me, so I could make it work with "id-button/"?

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I would probably implement a forked `LocaleMiddleware` to only accept 2 letters, instead of `\w+(-\w+)`.  You'd still have problems with posts named `id` or `nl`, but `id-button` would work. Not for the faint of heart, though.